# position:absolute; Из фрейма

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

На странице есть плавающий фрейм  и в нем есть таким способ реализованное всплывающее окно:
`#floatWindow{ display : none; }` затем 
`#floatWindow:hover{ display : block; }` и когда окно всплывает, то он позиционируется отоносительно фрейма а надо чтобы относительно всей страницы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте `flex`:

```css
div#frameContainer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.iframe {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
}

div#frameContainer,
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id='frameContainer'>
  <iframe></iframe>
</div>
```

Такой способ можешь использовать для любого болчного элемента.